# Excel Pivot Table Different Grand Total Row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am having an issue with creating a pivot table in a certain format. My end result would need to look like this:

```
Associate      Sales
John Doe         40%
Jane Doe         60%
Grand Total:  $1,000
```

If I use the display as percentage or another function in that list, it changes the Grand Total row as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a field twice by just clicking and dragging it into the values box twice. Then just set one to values and one to percentages.

I don't think you can have the total showing something different to the rows.

Comment: The goal is to have two different views in one column. But judging from your answer, this is not possible. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have access to Excel at the moment, but could you put two pivot tables underneath each other, link them via slicers and then manually hide the rows you don't want to see? You would just run into problems if the upper pivot table needed more rows, since they can't overlap.